# French Tessdata for tesseract 3.01

Tags: tesseract, ephesoft

I used Ephesoft Community Edition and there are Tesseract 3.01 but only eng files.
I need to find tessdata for French Language but impossible to find it.
I tried to used 3.02 tessdata files but tesseract crashed.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The language packs for the old versions can be found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/.